# Getting url data from web and using it in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job and part of it is going to a file in azure blob and getting the info
'https://bla.blob.core.windows.net/data/ips.txt'
the content is

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

id like jenkins to build a string array from it and pass it to another command.
problem is when i use:

```
def response = httpRequest 'https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/data/ips.txt'
```

and then
try pass the response to the other command there's a problem since the data coming as one big String:

```
1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2\3.3.3.3...
```

how can i convert this to String array?

Comment: well you can use the split method on your String and split it by "\n". See Documentation for Split in Groovy: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_split.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Split Method

There is a split method on Strings in groovy.  You can split your String into a list as follows

```
def str = "1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2\n3.3.3.3"
def strArr = str.split("\n") // this is what you want to send

// Printing the array so you can see it appropriately split
strArr.each{
    println it
}
```